# Upload image multipart/form-data via POST method

Tags: c#, api, post, multipartform-data

I am writing API automated tests using C#, getting:

> "StatusCode: BadRequest, Content-Type: application/json;
> charset=utf-8, Content-Length: -1)"

when running my API call. When I run in Postman it is working fine, when I copy request from Postman to C# I am getting an error.

Working Postman request:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://example.com/api/intake/Patients/2411b32f-0ce8-46f3-90dd-79fc57447a9a/identifications/DriverLicense/image");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer xxx");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
request.AddHeader("Cookie", "TS017becea=xxx");
request.AddFile("File", "C://Users//GK//Desktop//NuPogodi.PNG");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

My, not working request:

```
IRestClient client = new RestClient("https://example.com/api/intake/Patients/2411b32f-0ce8-46f3-90dd-79fc57447a9a/identifications/DriverLicense/image");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + GetAccessTokenStr);
request.AddParameter("boundary", Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), ParameterType.GetOrPost);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
request.AddFile("File", "C://Users//GK//Desktop//NuPogodi.PNG");
Response = client.Execute(request);
```

What am I missing? Do I need to convert image data to byte array?

> "{"type":"InternalServerError","message":"There was an unknown
> error handling this
> request.","errors":{},"exception":{"ClassName":"System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationException","Message":"Invalid
> image file type: application/octet-stream","Data"

Thank you,
Gene

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: "StatusCode: BadRequest, Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8, Content-Length: -1)"

Comment: "{\"type\":\"InternalServerError\",\"message\":\"There was an unknown error handling this request.\",\"errors\":{},\"exception\":{\"ClassName\":\"System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationException\",\"Message\":\"Invalid image file type: application/octet-stream\",\"Data\":{},\"InnerException\":null,\"HelpURL\":null,\"StackTraceString\":\"   at Task<IActionResult> DatStat.Connect.WebApi.Intake.Controllers.PatientsController.UploadIdentificationImage(Guid patientId, string type, ImageUpload model)+(string error) => { } in F:/Program

Comment: Maybe png is not a valid image type? By the way, you can edit your question add the error information instead of putting it in comments. While you are at it, you can look at [how to use markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Same png image working when call in Postman

Comment: Are you saying that you used Postman's code generation feature and that is what it gave you? I wonder if there is a bug in it because : [*Remember that AddFile will set all the necessary headers, so please don't try to set content headers manually*](https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#uploading-files). Have you tried using HttpClient?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Yes, I used Postman's code generation feature. Also, yes, I used HttpClient client with same result.

Comment: Found the issue. I was using wrong Content-Type. var request = new RestRequest(endpoint);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + GetAccessTokenStr);
            request.AddFileBytes("File", fileBytes, "NuPogodi.PNG", **"image/png"**);
            var client = new RestClient("https://example/api/");
            var response = await client.ExecutePostAsync(request);

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 8
You May Easy Call Multipart Api for image uploading directly using use GuzzleHttp\Client;

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Utils;
use File;

        $filename = $req->file('file1')->getClientOriginalName();
        $getfilePath  = $req->file('file1')->getRealPath();
        $client = new Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', 'http://127.0.0.1:8045/api/uploadImages', [
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name'     => 'image',
            'contents' => fopen($getfilePath, 'r')
        ],
        // 'headers'  => [
        //      'Content-Type' => '<Content-type header>'
        //  ]
       
    ]
]);
echo $response->getStatusCode();
$bodyresponcs = $response->getBody();
$result = json_decode($bodyresponcs);
print_r($result->status);
```

your Form in view file

```
<form action="/postsubmit" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
@csrf
<input type="file"  name="file1"   />
<button type="submit" class="btn long">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Api Code is here which is made on other project
this is the controller code laravel 8

```
  <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ApiPictureUpload extends Controller
{
    //
    

    private function uploadImage11($file){

        if($file == null ){
            $path = "";
        }else{
            $path = $file->store('public/docs');
        }
        return str_replace("public/","", $path);
    }

    public function uploadImage(Request $request){
        if(!$request->hasFile('image')) {
        return response()->json(['status'=>'false','message'=>'Upload File Not Find',], 400);
        }
 
        $images = $request->file('image');

        $extension = $images->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $allowedfileExtension=['jpeg','jpg','png'];

        $check = in_array($extension,$allowedfileExtension);
 
        // if($check) {
        $path= $this->uploadImage11($images);
        return response()->json(['status'=>'true','message'=>'Image Uploaded','path'=>$path,'exe'=>$extension],200); 
        // }
        // else{
            // return response()->json(['status'=>'false','message'=>'Image Should be Jpg, Jpeg, Png'], 400);

        // }
    }
}
```

Api Route code

```
Route::post('/uploadImage', [ApiPictureUpload::class,'uploadImage']);
```